# How to save special characters?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm saving some data in a .txt file so I can load/read it after, but some special characters do not work well.

I took a screenshot how it looks "inside" the string, because it saves some symbols in the file and when I load it doesn't load as it is suppose to.

Image with the characteres and how they are show in the string:

[image]

I'm using the WinAPI code to write and read the file: `WritePrivateProfileString()` and `GetPrivateProfileString()`

```
public static void FileWriteValue(string File, string Section, string Key, string Value)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, File);
        }

        public static string FileReadValue(string File, string Section, string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(100000);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 100000, File);
            return temp.ToString();
        }
```

Upddated with the Write and Read.

Comment: Are you using the same encoding to read and write to the file? Does the encoding that you're using support the special characters that you're trying to encode?

Comment: Updated with the code, remember that WritePrivate~ and GetPrivate~ are WinApi calls, so no code behind it.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use those WinApi calls instead of .NET framework calls for file access? Also, are you sure that it's not loading as it's supposed to? The Visual Studio debugger won't display many special characters, even if they are actually in the string.

Comment: Not really, I'm using it for a easier ini file structure acess, I dont know if the .NET has something to work like that, to write/read in INI files struct. The file saved will have different characters, in that example it saves something like "v +", it saves with other characters in the file, so when I read it the characters are different.